# Filter array with object of undefined keys T with type guard to T's with defined keys // could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript, generics, undefined

Goal: **Filter undefined values typesafe**

```js
  // Key b can be missing in this type:
  type AB_ = { a: string; b?: string | undefined, c?: string };
  // Key b can no longer be missing but its value type is unchanged
  type AB = { a: string, b: string | undefined, c?: string };

  const abs: AB_[] = [{ a: '', b: '' }, { a: '', c: '' }];
  const as: AB[] /* Type narrowed! */ = abs.filter(x => filterUndefinedKeys('b', x));
  // as === [{ a: '', b: '' }];
```

I want to filter all cases where the key `b` does not exist. Note that the key `c` can still optionally be present.

```js
export function filterUndefinedKeys<
  TValue extends { Key?: any },
  JValue extends { Key: any },
  Key extends string,
>(key: Key, value: TValue): value is JValue {
  return key in value
}
```

However I am receiving an error.

```
TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
Type  JValue  is not assignable to type  TValue 
 JValue  is assignable to the constraint of type  TValue , but  TValue  could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint  { Key?: any; }
```

How can I make typescript recognise that the key exists in the type without using `as`?

---

**Example Test case**:

```
// Tests types: https://www.totaltypescript.com/how-to-test-your-types
type Expect<T extends true> = T;
type Equal<X, Y> = (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends <T>() => T extends Y
  ? 1
  : 2
  ? true
  : false;

describe('filterHasNotUndefinedKeys()', () => {
  it('filters undefined keys', () => {
    // Arrange
    type Input = { a: string; b?: string | undefined; c?: string };
    type Output = { a: string; b: string | undefined; c?: string };
    const input: Input = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };

    // Act
    const output = [input].filter(filterHasNotUndefinedKeys('b'));

    // Assert
    type _ = Expect<Equal<Output, typeof output>>;
  });
});
```

Comment: I think there's a few levels of misunderstanding here. 1) filterUndefinedKeys should return a function if you want to use it like that. 2) You are trying to assign a nullable value to a non-nullable value in your type predicate `value is JValue`, which is unsafe. 3) This is a little tricky, because `in` just checks if the key exists in an object. Without `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`, your type `{ Key?: any }` allows the key to exist with a value of `undefined`.

Comment: A potential solution could look like this: https://tsplay.dev/mbyr3N - Note that `Required<MaybeB>` is structurally equivalent to `HasB`.

Comment: @katniss Thanks, I am just checking your solution. 1) I am aware of that, but tried to reduce the complexity. I fixed the use case. 3) I am aware that the values can still be `null | undefined`, but `(a.key === undefined) === (key in a)`.

Comment: @katniss I am not sure what the problem is with 2)? Your solution is correct in this case, but I was hoping to be able to make one additional property required. [SetRequired](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/set-required.d.ts) from type-fest would create such a type. I will adjust my example to reflect this use case.

Comment: @Patrick is this what you want? [tsplay.dev/m3oqqm](http://tsplay.dev/m3oqqm)

Comment: 2) is the reason why you get the error. If my code works for you then I'll go ahead and post an answer with a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: @katniss  Without additional boundaries TValue and JValue might be totally different types with a only shared key.  That's the interpretation of the error message isn't it?

Comment: @ekimboran First I have to address your playground. It doesn't quite work. Remove the type annotation on `as` and see what TS infers. It's `({ b: any; } & AB_)[]` which is not quite right. Second, yes, that could be one way of thinking about it.

Comment: @katniss Your solution does not quite work. If I change the type definition to `type MaybeB = { a: string; b?: string, c?: string };
type HasB = { a: string; b: string, c?: string };` then your method will make `c` required as well which is undesired.

Comment: @ekimboran `That's the interpretation of the error message isn't it?` > Yes, but I am not sure how to restrict it. Your code example seems to work. I am surprised to see that typescript seemingly treats `aAlsoMissing` the same as `aUndefined` in this example `type aUndefined = { b?: string };
type aAlsoMissing = { b?: string | undefined };`. At least that is what the typehint on tsplay shows. Even though the key `b` is defined to be a `string` if it exists, typescript seems to allow its value to be undefined.

Comment: @Patrick tsplay.dev/NaZ5Pm I hope i haven't missed anything else.

Comment: @ekimboran, thanks, but it still does not seem to work: `type Input = { a: string; b?: string | undefined; c?: string };
type Output = { a: string; b: string | undefined; c?: string };
const input: Input = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };

        // Act
const output: Output = [input].filter(filterUndefinedKeys('b'));
` now there is an error on the `output: Output` definition: `Type '({ b: string | undefined; } & Input)[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Output': a, b(2739`